# SpringBoot 2.2.4 Actuator - path for custom management endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator

After moving from spring-boot v1.3 to the newest spring-boot v2.2.4 we've lost the ability to have custom endpoints under management port.

Before we had our custom endpoints declared as:

```
@Component
public class CacheEndpoint implements MvcEndpoint {
 ...
   @Override
  public String getPath() {
    return "/v1/cache";
  }
  ...
  // mappings goes here
```

Since `MvcEndpoint` has been removed from spring-boot actuator now we need to do next:

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "cache")
public class CacheEndpoint {
    ...
    // mappings goes here
```

Unfortunately, we've lost an option to have a custom root path for our custom management endpoints (before it was `/v1/`)

For back-compatibility, we still want to have default actuator endpoints such as `health`, `metrics`, `env`.. to be under `/` base path. e.g. `host:<management_port>/health`, but at the same time we still want to support our custom endpoints under `/v1/` path, e.g. `host:<management_port>/v1/cache`

I tried a lot of things, `googled` even more, but no success yet. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for spring boot 2:

application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
      base-path: "/management" # <-- note, here is the context path
```

All-in-all consider reading a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#spring-boot-actuator) for actuator from spring boot 1.x to 2.x

Comment: That works, but for ALL endpoints, including actuator's default. E.g. /health, /metrics become /manage/health, /manage/metrics etc.. But we need to save base-path=/ for default actuator's endpoints and apply another base-path for out custom endpoints only .

Comment: I don't remember that I needed something like this in spring boot 1.x but why don't you just put a path /actuator/custom/path/my-custom-endpoint ? All-in-all I believe all endpoints for actuator should be under the same root path

Comment: It's a back-compatibility reason. Of course, we can move everything under one path, but there are a lot of things need to be reconfigured because of this. In edge case we will do this, but if there a way to configure this at the application level - better not to reconfigure a number of third-parties.